# Data truncated for column after change type field

Tags: mysql, ddl

After modify my field type from varchar(255) to varchar(300) i got a problems with my web service so i wanted to change it back to 255 using this:

```
ALTER TABLE `u_yf_crmentity_search_label` CHANGE `searchlabel` `searchlabel` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

But i can't because:

```
#1265 - Data truncated for column 'searchlabel' at row 23807
```

I tried insert data but there i still the same problem

table:

```
CREATE TABLE `u_yf_crmentity_search_label` (
  `crmid` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `searchlabel` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `setype` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `userid` text
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: On the table you show  in your create statement, the column can hold up to 300 characters. The ALTER statement decreases this size to 255 characters. If there is data in that column in one of the records that is longer than 255 characters, you will get this error/warning from MySQL. You could try to execute the `ALTER TABLE` query using `IGNORE`. `ALTER IGNORE TABLE etc...` Note: You WILL lose data since everything longer than 255 characters will be trimmed.

Comment: i trimmed data by substr() and changed for varchar(255). Thank you anyway for advise.